# How to append new json key and value pair to a middle of existing .json file using PowerShell without rewriting entire file

Tags: json, git, powershell

I have a existing .json file in GitHub similar to below.

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add new key and value to "maths" using Powershell. I tried below commands after cloned the git repo into my local directory

```
$FilePath = 'C:\Users\test.json

$y = Get-Content $FilePath | ConvertFrom-Json
$value = @`
   {
                "question": "12 - 6 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "6"
                ],
                "answer": "6"
      }
`@
$resultObject = $value | ConvertFrom-Json
$y.quiz.maths | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "q3" -Value $resultObject
$y | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | Set-Content -Path $FilePath
```

Then committed and pushed the changes. When I checked the comparasion between 'main' branch and my 'feature' branch, entire file has been rewritten because of new whitespaces.

Note:

1. "-compress" command did not help here
2. If I merge and again raise a PR with new values, It gives that specific commit only but this will continue unwanted whitespaces

Questions;

**1. Is there any proper way to do this without having unwanted whitespaces**

**2. Can we do it without converting into PowerShell object. I know we can convert it to a'String' using '-Raw' option, then how do we add above new property and make single commit which having only specific change**

**3. Is there any other way add new value to this .json file using PowerShell except above 2 options?**

Answer (score 0):

We can simply update the Powershell version to 7+ and use -Depth option when converting to PowerShell object and use same Depth option when converting back to the JSON file. This way, it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good place to use a [Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.3) that defines the structure of your "questions", it would allow to more easily add new ones to your Json file.

First step is to define the Class:

```bash
class Question {
    [string] $question
    [string[]] $options
    [string] $answer

    Question([string] $question) {
        $this.question = $question
    }

    [Question] AddOptions([scriptblock] $options) {
        $this.options = $options.Invoke()
        return $this
    }

    [Question] AddAnswer([string] $answer) {
        $this.answer = $answer
        return $this
    }

    [psnoteproperty] ToNoteProperty([string] $name) {
        return [psnoteproperty]::new($name, $this)
    }
}
```

Now that is done you can reuse it (create new questions) this way:

```bash
$newQuestion = [Question]::new('12 - 6 = ?').
    AddOptions{ 1, 2, 3, 6 }.
    AddAnswer(6).
    ToNoteProperty('q3')
```

And lastly, you can add this new question to your Json like this:

```bash
$json = Get-Content path\to\jsonfile.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
# `.quiz.maths` is the variable path here, the rest would remain the same
$json.quiz.maths.PSObject.Properties.Add($newQuestion)
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 | Set-Content path\to\jsonfile.json
```

Resulting Json from this example would be:

```json
{
  "quiz": {
    "sport": {
      "q1": {
        "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
        "options": [
          "New York Bulls",
          "Los Angeles Kings",
          "Golden State Warriros",
          "Huston Rocket"
        ],
        "answer": "Huston Rocket"
      }
    },
    "maths": {
      "q1": {
        "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
        "options": [
          "10",
          "11",
          "12",
          "13"
        ],
        "answer": "12"
      },
      "q2": {
        "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
        "options": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4"
        ],
        "answer": "4"
      },
      "q3": {
        "question": "12 - 6 = ?",
        "options": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "6"
        ],
        "answer": "6"
      }
    }
  }
}
```